# Python. Replace words with .replace in different steps

Tags: python, replace

I don't know why this isn't working. Sometimes just `word_1` is replaced with `word`, sometimes just `_` by whitespace.

Any ideas? This looks quite strange for me.

```
 f1 = open(file_name, 'r')
 f2 = open(file_name + '.tmp', 'w')
 for line in f1:
     f2.write(line.replace('word_1', 'word'))
 f1.close()
 f2.close()`

f1 = open(file_name, 'r')
f2 = open(file_name + '.tmp', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('word_2', 'word'))
f1.close()
f2.close()

f1 = open(file_name, 'r')
f2 = open(file_name + '.tmp', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('_', ' '))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Note that you keep reading from the original file, overwriting the temp file. Only the last replacement has an effect in the output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing over the first for loop. Without knowing what the string is, I think you are trying to do this:

```
f1 = open(file_name, 'r')
f2 = open(file_name + '.tmp', 'w')
for line in f1:
    new_line = line.replace('word_1', 'word').replace('word_2', 'word').replace('_', ' ')
    f2.write(new_line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Actually, for this to work, `.replace('_', '  ')` has to be the last one (after the word_2 one)

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to do that in this line:

```
f2.write(line.replace('_', ' '))
```

It is reiterating every other time, so the replaced name is not the same every time. I would have commented this, but I do not have enough reputation yet. Hope this helps.